# PDO Select query with unknown columns?

Tags: php, mysql

Im not sure how to better describe my question in the topic...

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE games (
            id INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR (255),
            player_1_id INT (3),
            player_1_status BOOLEAN,
            player_2_id INT (3),
            player_2_status BOOLEAN,
            player_3_id INT (3),
            player_3_status BOOLEAN
    )"
```

I need a query like:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare("
    SELECT id, name, turn
    FROM games
    WHERE player_1_id = :value1
    OR  player_2_id = :value1
    OR  player_3_id = :value1
");
```

But in addition, i want to select the column "player_x_status", depending on which "player_x_id" was found to equal :value1.
Im really dont know how i could better describe my problem, lacking terms here.

Can someone advice ?

Comment: This sounds like more of an SQL problem than PDO. Can you demonstrate a query in plain SQL that illustrates what you're trying to do in PDO?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `JOIN` here.

Comment: Sorry, i would not be able to solve this issue with SQL either.

Comment: Well, your SQL statements are clear. @mkaatman: Just drop the php part around them. _Perhaps_ SQL's [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement could be of help.

Comment: @C.Finke so you want something like `if player_x_id === value_1 get player_x_status`? (psudeocode).

Comment: @PerlDog I think he's saying his SQL doesn't do what he wants. In that case, the PDO is just complicating the problem.

Comment: @mkaatman Right. But his PDO (whatever that is) is quite simple. My elderly eyes don't even recognize it clearly. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you create a field named `something_N` **you can tell for sure that you are doing it wrong.**

What you have to do is another table to store all the players with statuses, like

- game_id
- player_id
- status

and you'll be able to select statuses for any players without problem.

This is how relational databases work.

Comment: Wow, that was just cruel :p

Thanks for the advice, ill rearrange the data into more tables.